# Struts 1.3 with tiles, reloading one tile out of 4 tiles

Tags: javascript, ajax, jakarta-ee, tiles, struts-1

I am using struts 1.3 with tiles. I want to reload another jsp from one jsp using ajax in javascript of first jsp. Both the jsp's are part of the tiles layout jsp, where four tiles are being inserted - title, header, body1, body2. I want to reload body 2 on some action done on body1 jsp. Please suggest. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your tiles-defs.xml do this

```
<definition name="page1" path="/layout.jsp">
    <put name="title" value="/title.jsp"/>
    <put name="header" value="/header.jsp" />
    <put name="body1" value="/somepage.jsp" />
    <put name="body2" value="/somepage.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Since you only want to reload body2's content

```
<definition name="page2" extends="page1">
    <put name="body2" value="/yourSecondPage.jsp" />
</definition>
```